# replace html string with object-values

Tags: javascript

I'am trying to have a function that replace variables in a string, but I do not get it.
my code:

```js
var insertReplacements = function (htmlStr, scope) {
  return htmlStr.replace(/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/g, function (_match, sub) {
    console.log(_match, sub)
    var tokens = sub.split('||');
    var value, token;
    while (token = tokens.shift()) {
      token = token.trim();
      console.log("token: ",token);
      // If string
      if (token[0] === '"') return token.slice(1, token.length - 1);

      // If query matches
      //value = whats to do here;

      if (value) return value;
    }

    return '';
  });
};

let works = "It_works";      
let uu = {
  message: 'use this message here.',
  learnMore: 'learn more',
  link: 'dai sit ein link',
  target: '_self',
  markup:  '{{uu.message}} test: {{"works"}} <a data-cc="uu.link" target="{{ uu.target }}" class="info" href="{{uu.link || "#null"}}">{{uu.learnMore}}</a>'
};
let i = insertReplacements(uu.markup,uu)
console.log("ii:",i)
```

The result of i should be:

```
'use this message here test: It_works <a data-cc="uu.link" target="_self" class="info" href="dai sit ein link">learn more</a>'
```

Comment: Just a quick question. Does it have to be a function? Because you can just use the backtick's to create a templatable string.  `let i = \`${uu.message}  test: ${works} <a ...\``.  I'm not sure if this works if your template isn't strict.

Comment: @Leroy: Sorry it has to be a function.

Comment: do you work with user supplied data? if so don't forget to prove your app against XSS attacks.

Comment: Maybe https://ejs.co does what you want (though it basically allows you to write all kinds of JS inside of your html.)

Comment: You're probably better off using a templating engine (like ejs or handlebars as Simon L mentioned), but if you're doing this for the sake of learning, then it'd be easier if you didn't supply the context in your template (ie: remove the `uu.`), as you're already providing that in your  `insertReplacements` call as the value for `scope`, then `value` should just be `scope[token]` at that point

Comment: This is not how its done. Take a step back, and solve this with a templating engine, server application, ...etc, but not with string interpolation.

Comment: [Maybe useful](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-nmqf7o?file=script.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You cannot pass variables values without their names since no names to find in the template, use `{uu, works}` as your scope.
2. [Construct `Function` objects to parse JS expression in your scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Function). We use `new Function()` to evaluate JS code inside a function. Using `eval` is more dangerous since variables in a template and in your code could clash, leak, etc. So using a function you pass only scope variables to evaluate.
3. Your `"works"` expression is a string, remove the quotes.
4. If you need add `try...catch` to the code to catch parsing errors during `Function` construction and when executing it.
5. Use caching to avoid calculating the same expressions.
6. A more advanced approach would be generating 1 function for processing a specific template and cache it, then reuse it for different scopes.
7. Remember that your data should be safe in terms of XSS. If not you should escape it. If you want to inject HTML with escaping you should have some additional mark that an expression should produce HTML.

```js
// a simple escape function could be like this
const span = document.createElement('span');
const escape = str => { if(!str) return str; span.textContent = str; return span.innerHTML; };

const insertReplacements = (html, scope, cache = {}, args = '{' + Object.keys(scope) + '}') => 
  html.replace(/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/g, (_, expr) => 
    (cache[expr] ??= escape(new Function(args, 'return ' + expr)(scope)) ?? '')
  );

let works = "It_works";      
let uu = {
  message: 'use this message here. <test>',
  learnMore: 'learn more',
  link: 'dai sit ein link',
  target: '_self',
  markup:  '{{uu.message}} test: {{works}} <a data-cc="uu.link" target="{{ uu.target }}" class="info" href="{{uu.link || "#null"}}">{{uu.learnMore}}</a>'
};

const parsed = insertReplacements(uu.markup, {uu, works});
console.log(parsed);
$div.innerHTML = parsed;
```

```html
<div id="$div"></div>
```

Comment: Thats's great Alexander. The part with the new Function I do not understand. Why I have to call a new function here?

Comment: @hamburger to evaluate JS code inside a function. using `eval` is more dangerous since variables in a template and in your code could clash, leak, etc. So using a function you pass only scope variables to evaluate.

Comment: @hamburger added the explanation to the answer

Comment: I use it only to pass hard-coded parameters to my html. Do I have an XSS-Problem with this?

Comment: @hamburger i guess no. XSS is about using untrusted 3rd-party data, for example data entered by users of a site. So you can remove `escape()` function then. But it allows to print `<>` characters as text not html though.